# Prediction Algorithm for Basketball Stats

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, pattern-recognition

I'm working on a project where I need to predict future stats based on past stats of basketball players.  I would like to be able to predict next season's statistics based on the statistics of the past three seasons (if there are three previous seasons to choose from).  Does anyone have a suggestion for a good prediction algorithm I could use?  The data is continuous and there can be anywhere between 5-14 dimensions (age, minutes, points, etc.)

Thanks!

Note:  I'd really like to use the program Weka to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Out of the box, [random forest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_forest) would likely give you a strong baseline, so I would start with this.

You can also try try [linear regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression), which is a simple yet relative effective method, but depending on the data might require a bit more tweaking (for example transforming some of the input and/or out variables).

[Gradient boosting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_boosting) regression is another strong predictor, but typically also needs more tweaking to work well.

All of these algorithms have Weka implementations.

Answer (score 0):

There obviously isn't one correct answer, but for anyone looking to do something similar, I'll better describe my problem and the solution that I've found.  I created a csv file where each row is a different season, and each column contains a different attribute.  For each attribute that I would like to predict, I have the stats for the current season and then another column for the stats for the previous season.  The first (rookie) season will have 0 for all 'previous season' columns.  With this data set, I loaded it into Weka and used a Multilayer Perceptron with the test-option set to Cross-Validation.  I set the number of folds to somewhere between 80-90% of the number of seasons available.

Finally, to predict the next season's statistics, you add one more row to the end and input the last-season values with "?" in the columns that you would like to predict.  If anyone would like a deeper example, I'd be glad to provide one.

Comment: I am a little confused on how you predicted the attributes. Can you show an example?

Answer (score 0):

I think also if you truly want to create an accurate prediction you have to look at player movement and if a player moves to a team with a losing record, do they increase their minutes to have a larger role which would inflate stats or move to a winning team for a lesser role where they could see a decrease in stats.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32118348)